# If a theme will undergo major changes would it be better to clone the parent instead of writting a child theme?

Tags: customization, child-theme, parent-theme

I started working on the customization of a theme following the recomendation of doing this using a child theme.

The problem I find is that a lot of the functionality of the theme needs to be changed (templates, functionality, javascript, styles, cpts, admin menus, options),  and I find it very time consuming to have to, besides of changing the functionality, having to place the changed code/files/templates in the child theme to be loaded correctly and make everything work smoothly. 
Luckyly the developers of the parent in this case use plugged in functions. If this weren't the case, it would be even more difficult to have this done.

I understand that a benefit of deriving a child theme is that you receive updates from the developers of the parent theme and these updates are isolated from the child code. Well in this case, as a lot customizaition has been done it is very likely that changes in the parent will have an impact in the child.

If I didn't use a child theme and I used a clone of the parent instead, I would download the updated parent in a separate folder, and just use BeyondCompare (or another diff tool) to see what has changed between the two versions of the parent, and do the retrofitting accordingly. Now, when using a child theme, I have to compare the updated parent with my current version of the parent. See what has changed and then check my customizations, which in the best case, will be in a file with the same name, and if I am less lucky they could be as loose functions in my functions.php or some php included by this last one. Not to mention that the retrofitting, apart from adding an extra step, it could also turn out to be quite more complicated.

So I was looking for some guidance upon a scenario like this one.

If a child theme allways is the way to go?

In which situations, if any, would the recomendation be to just clone the parent and make changes directly on top of it?

Thanks!

Comment: Im a big fan of non intrusive coding and a child theme is the way to go! any file you add into the child theme folder will be loaded instead of the equal file in the main theme. This means that when you update your settings are saved you can always compare and edit your child themes files but saves any accidents of not edit the file before uploading. This is the reason child themes was introduced. The next step would be creating a plugin to enqueue your own scripts to make sure they are always loaded including anything you add to a functions file can be done in a plugin keeping them separate.

Comment: There are pros and cons both ways - you've listed them already. The clone route is okay, as long as you do actually take the time to compare diffs each time an update is released. The child theme route is okay, but as you mentioned may cost extra time in comparison. A new theme may be the best solution. Try searching for a different parent theme that is closer to what you want as the end result, or code a completely custom theme. Perhaps something like Genesis or Thesis would give you the functionality you want but let you customize more fully.